# Is there a way to back to the lastest branch?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I always switch each between two branches, as develop and mywork, is there a better way to switch more quick except `checkout develop` and `checkout mywork`? As `cd -` in shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it works just like `cd` does in bash: `git checkout -`